# What are the basic steps should I follow to make a photo realistic avatar?

Tags: unity-game-engine, web, process, avatar

Can you help me find the right step by step process of rendering a photo realistic avatar in web?

Requirements:

1. I need a avatar for Men's tailor made suit that renders photo realistic fabric.
2. I need the avatar to move in circular motion seamlessly.
3. I need the avatar to be use in web browser or to be render in web.
4. How can I make it an API based?

Was it easier if I just could make this an app? or my browser need to download any plugin to render it smoothly?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Use DAZ3d, Zbrush, Mudbox or your skill in another 3d software. If your good your avatar will be good.
2. Make an animation of your avatar turning 360 degrees and loop it in Unity.
3. Use Unity to make webgl App
4. You can communicate from browser to your webgl App and you can make api how you like. If you explain your api needs i can be more precise.

Comment: Hi joreldraw, 

Thanks for giving your insights. Well the API needs:

1. Garment should be rendered on the server.

2. Website will pass API request with parameter to the server, rendering server will parse the parameter.
 
and render the garment based on the parameter. sample parameter is fabric, collar style and cuff.

Thanks you in advance.

Comment: have you many parameters combinations? really needed to render in server? or is posible to have rendered versión on server an use assetbundle?

Comment: should be rendered realtime, around 1000, fabric, 50 styling options, and its styling options may have around 20 possible values.

Comment: well really you simply change object texture. Only need to have ready your model with a nice Uvmap to match your textures, and have all textures in same aspect ratio to not got deformation. You can load your images from server in realtime wit www.get or can implement your api how a webservice and use UnityWebRequest to talk with this.

Comment: Was it possible that browser call unity API then Unity API call other API to get assets?

Comment: You can call functions from explorer to Unity WebGl App and inverse, check link https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/webgl-interactingwithbrowserscripting.html, and you can get direct TCP and HTML communication from your App.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you so much for giving your insights, well the API needs are:

1. Garment should be rendered on the server.
2. Website will pass api request with parameter to the server, rendering server will parse the parameter. 
   and render the garment based on the parameter. sample parameter is fabric, collar style and cuff.

Thank you in advance.